# How to ignore script tags in an excerpt pipe in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to build an excerpt pipe in my Angular app. The content is coming in from a JSON file API which contains HTML. Therefore, I am sanitizing it with `[innerHTML]` and. then the pipe for the excerpt cut-off at 90 characters.

Looks like this

```
<div 
  class="emp-content" 
  (click)="onClick(employee.id)"
  [innerHTML]="employee.content | excerpt:90"></div>
```

My pipe filter looks like this

```
  import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

  @Pipe({
    name: 'excerpt',
    pure: false
  })
  export class ExcerptFilter implements PipeTransform {
    transform(text: String, length:any ): any {
      if (!text || !length) {
        return text;
      }
      if (text.length > length) {
        return text.substr(0, length) + ' <span class="seemore">... see more</span>';
      }
        return text;
    }
  }
```

The problem I am having is script tags in the JSON break the functionality of this pipe. For example, in this case, the 90th character is part of the script tag in the JSON file so it adds the `class="seemore"` to it. This is unexpected, check it out:

```
<div class="emp-content"><p>Brother Michael Mulvaney has been named the UA's new Executive Vice President. <br><br class="seemore">... see more</p></div>
```

That class should not have been added to the `<br/>` tag

How can I modify the pipe filter so that it ignores script tags. In other words, ANY content inside < and > or < and />?

Comment: Addressing the "need more focus". The pipe filter I created doesn't ignore script tags. I need help modifying it so that it ignores script tags in the HTML. That way the 90 characters I am counting are actual text and not anything inside <> or </>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using regex in your code as follows:

```
var htmlStrippedText = text.replace(/<(.|\n)*?>/g, '');

  if (htmlStrippedText.length > length) {
    return htmlStrippedText.substr(0, length) + ' <span class="seemore">... see more</span>';
  }
return htmlStrippedText;
```

Comment: That simple! Thanks you!

Comment: Happy to help. :)